# What does it mean by "the history object is mutable"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a doubt from [the React Router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable) where it says *"the history object is mutable"* and gives an example as below:

> The history object is mutable. Therefore it is recommended to access
> the `location` from the render props of `<Route>`, not from
> `history.location`. This ensures your assumptions about React are
> correct in lifecycle hooks. For example:
>
> ```
> class Comp extends React.Component {
>   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
>     // will be true
>     const locationChanged =
>       this.props.location !== prevProps.location;
>
>     // INCORRECT, will *always* be false because history is mutable.
>     const locationChanged =
>       this.props.history.location !== prevProps.history.location;
>   }
> }
>
> <Route component={Comp} />;
> ```

In the above example code, shouldn't it be `===` instead of `!==` at both the places?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: the history object is mutable, i.e. its value can change without its identity changing. And no, it's `!==` because, as the variable name is intended to suggest, that's checking for _changes_ in the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Mutable `history`"* means that you have *only* 1 `history` object which is then being mutated(e.g. changed) after it's created. This means if you use the `history` object in the future for comparison like the following, you will **always** receive `false`. This is because `this.props.history` and `prevProps.history` point to the *same* and *only* `history` object(e.g they're equal). More about object comparison [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#comparing_objects) :)

```js
// INCORRECT, will *always* be false because history is mutable.
    const locationChanged =
      this.props.history.location !== prevProps.history.location;
```